# Error in loading page in laravel 5.3

Tags: laravel-5.3

I have problem in loading page i got error like below

[image]

I have route function as

```
Route::get('/courses', 'HomeController@getCourseList');
```

And my controller function is

```
public function getCourseList() { 
    $getCourse = Course::where('status', 1)->get();
    return view('courselisting')->with(['courses' => $getCourse]);
}
```

blade code for rendering page is

```
<a class="read_more_btn" href="{{ url('/courses') }}">Browse all the Course</a>
```

Comment: Seems like .htaccess is not setup correctly, as apache is looking for a folder "courses" instead of routing the request to PHP. Have a look at the [installation section](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3)

Comment: how to solve this problem

Comment: @Vinothini Go the the root/public of your project, add a .htaccess file like the following: [htaccess laravel configuration](https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/configuration#pretty-urls)

Comment: I cannot access course url alone other links are working fine..

Comment: I fixed issue the problem is i have courses.php file so i cannot use name of the file in route url